# Joining Two Tables, getting Aggregate and unique value of one

Tags: sql-server

This may have been answered previously, but I'm having a difficult time describing  my issue.

Let's say I have two tables

```
Table1 
User,  CalendarID 
Joe      1 
Joe      2 
Joe      3 
Sam      4
Bob      1 
Jim      2 
Jim      3

Table2
CalendarID,   CalendarTime
1             2014-08-18 00:00:00.000
2             2015-01-19 00:00:00.000
3             2015-08-24 00:00:00.000
4             2016-01-18 00:00:00.000
```

What I would like to do is Join the two tables, only getting a single User Name, and Calendar ID based on what is this highest CalendarTime associated with that CalandarID.

So I would like the query to return

```
User   CalendarID
Joe    3
Sam    4
Bob    1
Jim    3
```

The closest I've managed is

```
SELECT t1.User, MAX(t2.CalendarTIme) AS CalendarTime
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON t1.CalendarID = t2.CalendarID
Group By t1.User
```

Which gets me the User and CalendarTime that I want, but not the Calendar ID, which is what I really want.   Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest to your script and pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT t1.User, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON t1.CalendarID = t2.CalendarID
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1_2 
    INNER JOIN table2 t2_2
    ON t2_2.Calendar_ID = t1_2.Calendar_ID
    WHERE t1_2.User = t1.User
      AND t2_2.CalendarTime > t2.CalendarTime
  )
```

Comment: This did it.   Still haven't quite wrapped my head around why it works, but it does.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved for the top N per group:

using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
select top 1 with ties 
  t1.User, t1.CalendarId, t2.CalendarTime
from table1 t1
  inner join table2 as t2
    on t1.Calendarid = t2.Calendarid
order by row_number() over (partition by t1.User order by t2.CalendarTime desc)
```

or using [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)(or a derived table/subquery) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
  select t1.User, t1.CalendarId, t2.CalendarTime
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by t1.User order by t2.CalendarTime desc)
  from table1 t1
    inner join table2 as t2
      on t1.Calendarid = t2.Calendarid
)
select User, CalendarId, CalendarTime 
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Well you get 5 minutes after posting to finish up edits before it goes on the record.... unless someone comments on your post ^.^